# Mosquitto states Error Permission Denied when opening port

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have a Mosquitto broker running on a EC2 linux instance.  When I try to start mosquitto with the port set to 1883 it works fine, but when I try to start it with port 443 it says "Opening ipv4 port 443" and then the next line is "Error: permission denied".  I have that port open in my instance.  I can't find any information on this specific error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux and UNIX computers, ports below 1024 are restricted so that only processes running as root can listen on them. If your process isn't running as root it'll get a "permission denied" error when it tries to listen on that port or any other below 1024.

This was done by convention to ensure that servers running on well known ports could only be started by someone with administrative access to the computer. That prevents an ordinary user on a multiuser system from starting a malicious server pretending to be the official server on the system.

If you have to use a port below 1024, you can confirm this is the problem by making sure you start the server while running as root.

Running servers as root is not a great choice for production systems. Servers that have to listen on privileged ports will generally start as root, open the port, then de-escalate their privileges by changing their userid to a non-root user that's specific to the server. Then if a remote attacker manages to take advantage of a vulnerability in the server they'll have less access to the system than they would if the server ran as root.

If you run mosquito as root you be sure to use the *user* option in *mosquitto.conf* to set the username mosquitto should switch to after it starts up.

BTW, 443 is a peculiar choice for running an MQTT broker as it's the port that's used by HTTPS.

Comment: 443 for a MQTT over websockets with TLS is not that bad an idea

Comment: Thank you for your assistance and the full explanation.  This was exactly the answer.

Comment: There is a easy solution to allow Mosquitto use privileged ports with systemd. Just edit the service description file (in Ubuntu, /lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service) and add two lines under [Service]:
  AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
  User=mosquitto
Then execute "sudo systemctl daemon-reload" and "sudo service mosquitto restart".